# If I want to upgrade a package in AptGet, where do I go to contribute?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, package-management

I am on Ubuntu 16.04. I use apt-get a lot to install packages/libraries for development, but the problem is a lot of the libraries in apt-get is very out of date (just to name a few, cmake, glog ... etc), hence I have to build them from source to get the up to date libaries. If I want to contribute to Apt to upgrade some of the outdated packages, where should I go to?

The equivalent of apt-get on windows [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg), allows us to submit pull requests to update and add libraries. Hence the libraries on vcpkg is very up to date and there is minimal need to build libraries from source in windows.

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I start my own Repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2238/how-can-i-start-my-own-repository)

Comment: Ubuntu have packages "outdated" intentionally. Allegedly it improves stability *(it's usually not)*. Out off top of my head, you have three ways: α) quit using LTS *(they're especially outdated)*, β) use your own repo, γ) change to a bleeding edge distro.

Comment: Btw, is there a difference between vcpkg and cygwin? From github description it looks like vcpkg reinventing a wheel, and you'd probably want Cygwin for it have far bigger repository of libs and utilities.

Comment: @Hi-Angel libs in cygwin are even more outdated than Apt, a lot of the libs I need is missing and it doesn't integrate well with CMake. Starting my own repo seems like a possible option to go if there is no way I can contribute to Apt...